# External hard drive : Problems were found with the partition map

Tags: disk-utility, partition, external-disk

I have an external hard drive which carries all my most precious files (some are backed up on a second hard drive, but not terribly recently).

I decided to "encrypt" this hard drive (which I immediately regretted), and now the drive won't open. I know the password, but once it's entered, it says that the drive can't be recognized, giving me the options to "Initialize..., Ignore, or Eject".

I then run Disk Utility First Aid, which says that "Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting."

Please tell me there is something I can do to recover my data.

Comment: What does "which I immediately regretted" mean? Did you cancel the encryption process? Please get the partition map by entering: `sudo gpt -r show diskX` (with X probably 1 or 2) in Terminal.app and add the result  to your question!